# ScrollController animateTo method won't fire during the NotifcationListener's onNotification method

Tags: listview, flutter, scroll

I have a horizontal ListView. After the user releases their finger and the ListView slows to a stop, I want the view to place the centermost widget directly in the center of the ListView.

To do this, I have a NotificationListener:

```
child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
            onNotification: onNotification,
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: _controller,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 30,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return _buildProfileIcon(context, index);
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Whose onNotifcation method checks that the scroll ends:

```
bool onNotification(ScrollNotification scrollNotification) {
  if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
    _centerElement(findCenterElement());
  }
  return null;
}
```

In order to find and center the element already closest to the center:

```
int findCenterElement() {
  double offset = _controller.offset + 2*profileWidth;
  int centerishElement = offset < profileWidth
    ? 0
    : ((offset - profileWidth) / profileWidth).ceil();
  return centerishElement;
}



void _centerElement(int index) {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    double viewWidth = renderBox.size.width;
    _controller.animateTo(
      (profileWidth*index - viewWidth/2 + profileWidth/2),
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
    );
  }
```

I have the same centerElement(int index) method being called by a GestureDetectors onTap() method on these profile icon widgets (the widgets that this ListView is listing), and it centers the elements just fine. Setting breakpoints shows that, indeed, when onNotification fires as a ScrollEndNotification, _centerElement() is being called and so is the _controller.animateTo() method within it. But in the case of the NotificationListener event, animateTo() does not actually move the list.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll has no end, so can not `animateTo` somewhere,

```
if (scrollNotification is UserScrollNotification && scrollNotification.direction == ScrollDirection.idle) {
              scrollcontrol.animateTo(100, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.ease);
            }
```